# Error: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.7, django-suit

intento que me salga el valor de un nodo, pero me salta el error del asunto.

Antes en la línea donde me salta el error lo tenía de otra forma para que me diese otro valor, pero al cambiarla y poner otra función me da el problema.

No sé si también tengo algún fallo en el def modelo_code

Tengo este código:

```
def modelo_code(self, marca: Optional[Marca], code: str) -> Tuple[Optional[Modelo], List[Marca]]:
        if not marca or not code:
            return (None, [])
        cache_key = (marca.pk, code)
        if cache_key not in self.modelo_cache:
            try:
                modelo = marca.modelo_customer.get(code=code)
                marca_list = list(modelo.marcas.all())
            except Modelo.DoesNotExist:
                modelo = None
                marca_list = []
            self.modelo_cache[cache_key] = (modelo, marca_list)
        return self.modelo_cache[cache_key]
        
    
    
def code_modelo(self):
    return self._data_cache.modelo_code


def nodo_Codecar(self, operacion: Operacion, sentido: str,
                 marca_list: List[Marca],
                 Codecar: Optional[Union[Marca, Contact]] = None) -> etree.Element:
    nodo = etree.Element("Buyer" if sentido == "COMPRA" else "Vendedor")
    for marca in marca_list:
        nodo.append(self.Id_operacion(operacion, marca))
    if Codecar:
        market = etree.SubElement(nodo, "Codecar")
        if CocheDataCache.is_promocion(Codecar):
            etree.SubElement(market, "SERIE").text = self.code_modelo(Codecar) # Error:  takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
        else:
            market.append(self.Cliente(operacion, Codecar))
    return nodo
```

He probado de muchas formas, pero no consigo que me funcione

Comment: Tu función `code_modelo` no acepta parámetros, y le estás pasando `self.code_modelo(Codecar)`

Answer (score 0):

Tu función `code_modelo` no espera más argumentos que self, que pertenece a la instancia de la clase y que es un argumento posicional y le estás pasando 2 argumentos, si deseas que reciba más argumentos debes agregarlos como hicistes con las demás funciones.

```
def code_modelo(self, parametro2):
    return self._data_cache.modelo_code
```

Comment: Eso es lo 1º que probé y no funciona cuando lo pongo da un error muy parecido y en el pycharm en la función nodo_Codecar, en la línea que tengo el comentario te pone el cierra paréntesis de color amarillento como daría algún tipo de error